# Python - iterating over a dictionary and changing the dictionary - how to?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a function to choose a winner in a system based on majority.  If there's no majority, then I need to remove the choice with the least votes and keep going until there is a winner with the majority of the votes.  For example,

```
voting({'a':12, 'b':9, 'd':4})
```

In this case, `'a'` has 12 votes, `'b'` has 9, and `'d'` has 4.  Since `'a'` does not have a majority (12/25 votes), I need to remove `'d'` from the available choices, and it will have the majority (12/21).  There may be any number of choices in each "ballot", all that matters is the number one in each.

My code is for `def voting(votes)`:

```
d = {}
winning_party = ''
i = 0
for key in votes.keys():
    d[key] = votes[key]
while winning_party == '':
    for key, vote in d.items():
        if d[key] > 0.5 * sum(d.values()):
            winning_party = key
            return winning_party
        else:
            if d[key] == min(d.values()):
                del d[key]
```

I've tried making minor changes but I either get an error that the dictionary changed in size during iteration, or the function stopped working.

Can anyone help me fix the code, or tell me how I can avoid changing the dictionary while it's in the loop?  I can only really use the code above, i.e. I can't import anything or use anything other than basic functions.

Comment: If `('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'):12` means "a got 12 votes", then the rest of the letters seem superfluous. Indeed in your code you throw them away. I can see this is developing into a 'transferable vote' system, but as it stands, you should remove details like this from your question.

Comment: This doesn't exactly deal with your problem, but can't you get the same result by just selecting the candidate with the most votes?  I don't think iterating over the dictionary is necessary?

Comment: You're right, I should've edited that part out, fixed now!

Comment: What happens (or is suppposed to happen) given `{'a':10, 'b':10, 'd':4}` ?

Comment: I haven't decided what to do about ties, either the first of the choices in the tie will win or I'll rerun the election with different numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while winning_party == '':
    total_votes = sum(d.values())    # Recompute the total before each iteration.
    for key, vote in d.items():
        if d[key] > 0.5 * total_votes:
            winning_party = key
            return winning_party

    min_party = min(d, key=d.get)    # Find key having minimum votes.
    del d[min_party]                 # Delete it.
```

Comment: You're both right, fixed, thanks.  It still changes the dictionary during iteration though...

Answer (score 2):

What @FMc said, except that you're testing inequality against the minimum instead of testing for equality. In other words you want:

```
if d[key] == min(d.values()):
    del d[key]
    total_votes = sum(d.values())
```

(Note the == instead of !=)

Comment: Maybe add a break statement after updating total_votes? That should break out of the d.items() iteration and re-iterate since your while loop will still continue.

Answer (score 1):

Your question has bee answered, but I thought this was an interesting problem so here is my solution.

```
def findmajority(votes):
  major = max(votes, key=votes.get)
  if sum([v for k,v in votes.iteritems() if k != major]) < votes[major]:
    return major    
  del votes[min(votes, key=votes.get)]
  return findmajority(votes)

>>> votes = {'a': 10, 'b': 9, 'c':4}
>>> findmajority(votes)
'a'
```

A few things to take into account:

- It will not regulate ties, and will return one of the winners, not all.
- It will **modify your existing `votes` structure**. You could get around this by either making a copy of the dict when passed to the function, or creating a new dict on each recursion.